# positioning relative to centered element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have trouble with positioning my CSS menu - `.dropdown` regard to centered image - `#logo`, it has to have absolute position, I wrote a function which should do this:

```
$(function() { 
      var $logo = $('#logo');
      var marginRight = ($(window).width() - ($logo.offset().left + $logo.outerWidth()));
      $('.dropdown').css('marginRight', marginRight);
});
```

It works fine in IE, but not always in Chrome and Firefox. Why?
This is the website:

[site during production](http://www.krzew.cyberhelp.pl)

Comment: Positioning is styling and should preferably not be done with JavaScript.

Comment: @SvenvandeScheur I mean, you're right, but there are reasons to do this. I think we can all agree, especially when it comes to Centering, that you have to work a little bit outside the box. For some reason it's an issue that web standards just can't seem to provide a decent, easy solution for.

Comment: 9/10 you can do this without js. For instance with flexbox/margin and or a transform: translate(). Unfortunatly. It's not clear to me whats the goal is. Without a stripped down fiddle I can't recommend anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try just set

```
$('.dropdown').css('right', margright);
```

Comment: It did not help. When you vistit this for the first time (or after cleaning cache) in firefox the menu shows too much on the right, when you refresh it looks good..

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your code:

```
$('#logo').on('load', function() {
   // you code here
});
```

Because you wrote code inside document ready callback, but image does not load yet and do not know its sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say where exactly you want to position your dropdown menu but assuming you want it to be in the middle beneath the logo you can do this

```
$(function() { 
    var logo = $('#logo');

    logo.on('load', function() {
        var left = logo.offset().left + logo.outerWidth()/2;
        $('.dropdown').css('left', left);
    });
});
```

Comment: It not help, I want put the dropdown menu under right side of the logo, when I put this code firefox behaviour is strange

Answer (score 0):

@SvenvandeScheur, thanks for attention. I found the solution (the javascript code works fine on page), but it would be intresting for all how to do this with flexbox.
I want the dropdown menu to put under the bottom right corner of centered image

https://jsfiddle.net/1ddk7e5k/

This code works on the page:

`$( "#logo" ).load(function() {
          var margright=(($('.centered').width()-$('#logo').width())/2);
          $('.dropdown').css('marginRight',margright);
});`